# wamp 3 not using tables with innodb engine

Tags: mysql, wamp, wamp64

I just installed wamp 3.0.6 and I had wamp 2 already so I wanted to use my old databases, then I copied theme from `wamp/mysql/data` to `wamp64/mysql/data`. but I see that not all tables are there, I see only table that have table.myi (MyISAM engine) and table with .ibd (innodb engine) are not shown. 
I tried to shutdown wamp 3.0.6 and run the old one but it always uses the new data of wamp 3.0.6 
the Q is how can I get my old databases running on the new installation of wamp knowing that I have two wamps:  c:/wamp64 and c:/wamp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all is not lost, but you have potentially damaged your new install, so can I suggest you start by uninstalling the WAMPServer 3 and removing the \wamp64 folder if it is not done by the uninstall.

Then reinstall WAMPServer 3.0.6 and then check it can run the `localhost` homepage.

Now install the WAMPServer 3.0.8 upgrade, its an ADDON that will install over 3.0.6.

Now to recovering the old databases.

1. Stop WAMPServer.

*If for example the old version was MYSQL5.6.17*

2. Copy `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17` and all its subfolders to `\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17`
   **Do not overwrite the new version folder**
3. Start WAMPServer again from the desktop icon.

*You should now have both the old MYSQL and the new MYSQL available within WAMPServer*

4. Switch the current version of MYSQL to the old mysql5.6.17 version using the wampmanager menus like this

   `left click wampmanager icon -> MYSQL -> Version -> MYSQL5.6.17 _(click this version number)_`

*wait a few second for WAMPServer to activate the old version of MYSQL. When the icon goes Green it is done*

5. Now using phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you like to use like MYSQL Workbench take a backup(EXPORT) of each of the databases you want to move to the newer version of MYSQL. Only backup YOUR databases not MYSQL's own i.e. not `mysql`. Save each backup somewhere safe, not in either WAMPSever folder structure.

*Now we will activate the new version of MYSQL lets assume this is MYSQL5.7.*
6. Using the wampmanager menus again activate the new MYSQL.

```
left click wampmanager icon -> MYSQL -> Version -> MYSQL5.7.14 _(click this version number)_
```

_Wait for the wampmanager icon to go Green again.

7. Now RESTORE all the backups you took from the old version to this new version.

You shoud now be ready to go. You can delete the old version of MYSQL from the new version of WAMPServer if you want to, by deleting the \wamp64\bin\muysql\mysql5.6.17 folder.

Restart WAMPServer and the old version of MYSQL will have gone.